# How to render a new component after successfull login using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've made a very simple `Login` component for learning purpose. If the user enters the correct username and password he should see the `Homepage`. Login mechanism is working fine. I'm not able to redirect to Homepage after successful login.

**users.json**

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Username": "mike",
    "Password": "User1Password"
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Username": "robert",
    "Password": "User2Password"
  }
]
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
...
import UserProfiles from './users.json';
import Home from '../Home/Home';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      loginStatus: 'not logged in',
    };
  }

  ...

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    var found = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    UserProfiles.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.Username == this.state.username) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if (found) {
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: 'Successfully logged in!',
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: 'Login failed!',
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-form">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            //USERNAME AND PASSWORD FIELDS
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**Home.js** is very simple as of now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world! Welcome to homepage</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I'm new to React. Please pitch in. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2vav6x?file=src%2Fcontainers%2FLogin%2FLogin.js).

Comment: try to use `boolean` type for `loginStatus`, The problem may not be solved, but it helps you `debug better`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the code like this :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-48hgqd?file=src/index.js

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-48hgqd?file=src/containers/Login/Login.js

The following code is work:

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Home from './containers/Home/Home.js';
import Login from './containers/Login/Login.js';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename="/">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/home">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { Form, FormGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import { Label } from 'reactstrap';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import UserProfiles from './users.json';
import './Login.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      loginStatus: 'not logged in',
    };
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    var found = false;
    event.preventDefault();
    UserProfiles.forEach((user) => {
      // as of now checks for correct username only and not the password
      if (user.Username == this.state.username) {
        found = true;
      }
    });
    if (found) {
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: 'Successfully logged in!',
      });
      console.log(this.props);
      this.props.history.push('/home');
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loginStatus: 'Login failed! Inavlid User/Pass',
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-form">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="username">Username:</Label>
            <Input
              id="username"
              name="username"
              placeholder="For e.g. tmtanzeel"
              onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="examplePassword">Password</Label>
            <Input
              id="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="enter your password"
              onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
              type="password"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </Form>
        <h2>{this.state.loginStatus}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```